# Duality and Concreteness in Category Theory

Tags: category-theory

I'm sorry for the silly question, but is it true that the opposite of a concrete category is also concrete?

Moreover, if I have a category and a faithful functor from it to a concrete category, may I deduce by composing the faithful functors that even the starting category is concrete?

Comment: If you assume there is a faithful functor $U:\mathcal C\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}$, then there is a faithful functor $U^{op}:\mathcal C^{op}\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}^{op}$. Can you find a faithful functor $F:\mathbf{Set}^{op}\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}$? In which case, $C^{op}$ is indeed concrete with the functor $F\circ U^{op}:\mathcal C^{op}\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}$ (since composition of faithful functors is still faithful)

Comment: So also the second question is true? And if I have two concrete category and consider their product, is it again concrete?

Comment: Well, the second question is true, again because composition of faithful functors is faithful. So if you have $F:\mathcal C\rightarrow\mathcal D$ and $U:\mathcal D\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}$, both faithful, then $U\circ F:\mathcal C\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}$ is faithful. The product $\mathcal C\times\mathcal D$ as well is concrete, because you can compose the functor $\mathcal C\times\mathcal D\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}\times\mathbf{Set}$, with any faithful functor $\mathbf{Set}\times\mathbf{Set}\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}$ (for example, the functor $(X,Y)\mapsto X\times Y$).

Answer (score 1):

There is small subtlety to pay attention to here. If by $C$ is concrete you mean that there exists a faithful functor to sets, then your question is answered in the comments. However, if by $C$ is concrete you mean "I have chosen a faithful functor to sets", then things are different. The question is what do we take the category of concrete categories to be. Are its objects concrete categories but with no specified functor to sets, or is it concrete categories with a choice of such a functor. In the latter case, the opposite is not concrete since there is no canonical functor $\mathbf {Set}^\mathrm {op}\to \mathbf {Set}$. In that case the opposite of a concrete category of $\mathbf {Set} $ is a concrete category over $\mathbf {Set}^\mathrm {op}$.

Comment: Concrete means that the category $\mathfrak{C}$ is equipped with a faithful functor from $\mathfrak{C}$ to Set

Comment: Then the opposite category is not concrete.

Comment: Well, here there is a problem with terminology. I see in many books that there is a difference between concrete and concretizable. A concrete category is a pair $(\mathfrak{C},F)$, where $F$ is a faithful functor to ${\bf Set}$; while a category $\mathfrak{C}$ is said concretizable if there exists a faithful functor from $\mathfrak{C}$ to ${\bf Set}$, Now, when you say "I have chosen a faithful functor to sets", you're using the notion of concrete. Well, I'm doing questions having in mind concretizability. I'm sorry for the misleading terminology of the question.

Comment: Precisely because of that I phrased my answer the way I did. You can take from it what suits your notion of concrete. It is unfortunate that the terminology is not 100% clear on this one. Alas.